# How to create a Word Wrap MenuItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, word-wrap

i'm a newbie in DOT NET

I'm building a `WPF` App using C# in which I have a `MenuItem` (Checkable) for toggling the Word Wrap feature on  and of for a **TextBox**(Just like in Notepad) i.e to switch between `TextWrapping="Wrap"` and `TextWrapping="NoWrap"`

**MenuItem** :

`<MenuItem Header="_Word Wrap" Name="wordWrap" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Checked="wrap_Click"/>`

**TextBox**:

`<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"  AcceptsReturn="True"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="txtContent">`

How to create a function so that , when the MenuItem is checked, it turns the Word wrap feature on and  when the MenuItem is unchecked, it turns the Word wrap feature off

I tried the following piece of code ,

```
private void wrap_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (wordWrap.IsChecked)
                txtContent.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            else
                txtContent.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
        }
```

but it shows an Exception at `txtContent.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;` :

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Please help me

Thank you !

Comment: What do you think "Object reference not set" means?

Comment: it's a NullReferenceException @lboshuizen

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: `txtContent.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;` @wdosanjos

Comment: Are you calling the `wrap_Click` method directly somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a problem with your actual event. Just try changing your event to a click event.

So, change this:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Word Wrap" Name="wordWrap" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Checked="wrap_Click" />
```

To this:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Word Wrap" Name="wordWrap" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Click="wrap_Click" />
```

This solved the problem for me. You don't even have to change the event code. It is correct. For some reason, the compiler just didn't like having it as a checked event...

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked !... But why didn't the `checked` event work ? @SuperPrograman

Comment: @AdityaVikas it is something to do with having the menu item previously checked. For instance, if you kept the event as a `Checked` event, but changed the `IsChecked` property to `false`, the program works fine. It is just having it already checked... Not totally sure myself.